# Graceful restart of Apache under Windows will shutdown the service

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I've a apache2 service (called wampstackApache-1)

When I do a graceful restart of the service with

```
C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.31-0/apache2/bin/httpd.exe -k restart -n wampstackApache-1
```

the service is stopped. What 's the reason? (The config file is immediately changed before the restart command and the config file is correct).

When I restart the service with

```
C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.31-0/apache2/bin/httpd.exe -k stop -n wampstackApache-1 && C:/Bitnami/wampstack-5.6.31-0/apache2/bin/httpd.exe -k start -n wampstackApache-1
```

everything works fine.
The Apache version is 2.4.25. (The graceful restart should be supported by this version)

What is looking strange to me: The same `httpd.exe -k restart -n wampstackApache-1` on an other machine (with Apapche2.4.38) is working fine there.

Why is this not working in this installation? What could be the reason? How can a perform a graceful restart of the apache service under WIN?

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the Apache Log Files. They say:

```
Fatal Error Unable to reattach to base address
```

The Problem was with my (old) php Installation.

https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/167

So I had to disable the OPCache on my installation. (opcache is not a must-have on this machine)

Now it is working.